# Developing facebook canvas app on localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am new to Facebook app development. Trying to develop a test app but I don't have a SSL certificate on my host, hence no https access, as Facebook requires for "Secure Canvas URL".

This is what I did, but the app shows a blank page:

Basic settings:

```
1. App Domains: http://localhost/
2. Canvas URL: http://localhost/mytestapp/
3. Secure Canvas URL: <empty>
```

Advanced settings:

```
1. Valid OAuth redirect URIs : http://localhost/
```

Please let me know of any changes in settings to get this work or if there is any other way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Secure Canvas URL set as Facebook now exclusively uses HTTPS. Depending on the local server software you're using, you should be able to create a self-signed SSL certificate to use. This will let you serve HTTPS pages from your localhost.

Comment: i had a tough time trying to generate a self-signed certificate for my localhost xampp. have you tried using this way before? and, maybe if you have any links please on how to actually do this? googled, but not a decent tutorial on this.

Comment: I use MAMP on my Mac, which has a one-click self-signed certificate setup, which made things easier for me.